# Steaming and seasoning veggies in a pressure pot?

Tags: steaming

I am an extreme novice when it comes to food prep. My daughter bought me a pressure pot. I have the Aozita brochure for steaming veggies. When do I season , before? during? or after steaming? What is meant  by drizzle?

Answer (score 1):

It depends... (taking carrots with rosemary as an example)

- If using dried herbs, add them beforehand so they get steamed together with the veggies
- if using fresh: crush and add afterwards

(or a combination of both)

Answer (score 0):

I'd season after steaming the vegetables.

See this question

[How to add flavouring ingredients to steamed or boiled veggies?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32804/how-to-add-flavouring-ingredients-to-steamed-or-boiled-veggies)

Drizzling a liquid (mostly) is slowly pouring liquid in small amount.

See this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5F9Oxi_bxmY